# Can't download magestead box

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to setup magento on magestead. However, I'm always getting an error during downloading the `richdynamix/magestead-ubuntu14-nginx-php56` box.

The error is:

> An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
>   message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
>   again.
>
> SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is better related to the StackOverflow. Anyway, check that you have [openssl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) installed and turned on. Additional information about how to debug correct error number you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876563/curl-request-is-failing-on-the-ssl)